# Create a dictionary while keeoping the keys from another dictionary. - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, dot-product

I would like to be able to make a new dictionary with the values I get from running my code, but I want to keep the values from the first dictionary.

```
import math
d = {'bob':[5,0,0,1,3], 'toms':[3,0,5,3,0], 'sammy': [0,0,0,1,0], 'ted':[5,0,0,6,3]}
highScores = {}

total = 0
v =0
whatName = str(input("what name do you want?   "))
for i in d:
    a = d[whatName] #gives us whatNames values
    b = d[i]
    if i == whatName: #skips what name is
        pass
    else:
        for k in range(len(b)):
            #print(k, end = ' ')
            value = a[k]*b[k]
        
            total= value + total
            
        print(total) 
        total = 0
```

my output is:
18, 1, 40 and this is what goes into the "total" variable.

I would like these numbers to be the values in my new dictionary (highScores), while keeping the keys from the old dictionary (d).

The new dictionary should not have the name that is input from the user. So if I put in "bob", he should not be appearing in the new dictionary, and so on.

The new dictionary output should be something like:
highScores = {'toms':18, 'sammy': 1, 'ted': 40}

Thanks!

Comment: It's difficult to sus out what your variables are. Consider giving them more descriptive names, rather than `d`, `v`, `a`, `b`

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {'bob':[5,0,0,1,3], 'toms':[3,0,5,3,0], 'sammy': [0,0,0,1,0], 'ted':[5,0,0,6,3]}
highScores = {}

for x in d.keys():
    highScores[x] = sum(d[x])

print(highScores)
```

Output was:
{'bob': 9, 'toms': 11, 'sammy': 1, 'ted': 14}

Here I made highScores use all the names or "keys" in d, and added up the arrays, use d.keys() or d.values() to parse thru dicts.

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in d.keys():
    if key != whatName:
        high_scores[key] = sum(d[key])
```

Comment: Thanks! This helps in skipping the name that is put in by the user so thank you for that. But my key values are not correct, I want it to show the total variable here. Any idea on how to do that?